# Cannot execute binary file when calling its whole path

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use the *bison* utility in Linux Ubuntu 16. The binary file is located at */usr/bin/bison* set by the *`sudo apt-get bison`* command.

However, when I call bison from bash it looks like it works, but if I call the bison using its path, I get the following error (can be seen in screenshot)

```
Cannot execute binary file
```

[image]

Note that the path of the binary is gotten with `*type -a bison*`

Also, alongside the bison binary in /usr/bin, there is another file called *bison.yacc* which contains:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec '/usr/bin/bison' -y "$@"
```

Is there any reason to that problem? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.` (or its effective alias, `source`) with *binaries*.

`.` / `source` is intended for executing *shell* code in the context of the *current* shell.

*Binaries* can only run in a *child* process, so you invoke them *directly*:

```
/usr/bin/bison
```

`exec` also creates a new process, but it *replaces* the current shell.